# How to clear HTML5 filesystemsync?

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker, html5-filesystem

I am using HTML5 filesystemsync I am trying to clear the filesystem but I readEntries not returning entries.

Here is my code

```
function clearFileSystem(){
        trace("request to clear file system");
        try{
            var fs= webkitRequestFileSystemSync(TEMPORARY, 1024);

            var dirReader = fs.root.createReader();
            trace("writer initialized");

            dirReader.readEntries(function(entries) { //function not firing

                trace("reading entries in file system"); 
              for (var i = 0, entry; entry = entries[i]; ++i) {
                if (entry.isDirectory) {
                  entry.removeRecursively(function() {}, errorHandler);
                } else {
                  entry.remove(function() {}, errorHandler);
                }
              }
              trace("file system cleared");
            }, errorHandler);
            }
        catch(e){
            trace(e.message);
        }
    }
```

I read the API but I havent found any changes to do.
is there anything need to change for sync filesystem?